# Auto submit form with argument from URL

Tags: 7, forms

I have Drupal module with a form and it works just fine (/my_module/search)
I need menu hook for `my_module/search/%` and to be auto submitted and repopulate the form with the argument form url. So basically I need the same form just with the argument form URL submitted.

Comment: Not really sure what your question is, but I will throw this out there. You can use `drupal_get_path();` to get the url of your form. You can then use php [str_replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp) function to get rid off the `/my_module/search/` part and just be left with the `%` part.